# Function with multiple return types

Tags: c++, c++11

I have two enums which basically determine (on runtime) what to do. The 'mapping' looks something like

```
struct Foo { class CA; class CB; class CC; CA a; CB b; CC c; };
enum Base { A, B, C };
enum Func { X, Y };
Foo foo;

// A, X => use(foo.a.x());
// A, Y => use(foo.a.y());
// B, X => use(foo.b.x());
// B, Y => use(foo.b.y());
```

The problem is, that `a`, `b` and `C`, as well as the return types of `x()` and `y()` are all of different types (some really huge template types).

Mapping the two enums using switches or ifs is pretty ugly and requires lots of effort so I wondered, if I could somehow write something like this:

```
struct Foo { class CA; class CB; class CC; CA a; CB b; CC c; };
enum Base { A, B, C, };
enum Func { X, Y, }; 

template <typename T> auto applyFunc(Func f, T t)
{
    switch(f)
    {
        case X: return t.x();
        case Y: return t.y();
    }
}


auto getBase(Base b, Foo f)
{
    switch(b)
    {
        case A: return f.a;
        case B: return f.b;
        case C: return f.c;
    }
}


Func f;
Base b;
Foo foo;

use(applyFunc(f, getBase(b, foo)));
```

**Edit 1:**
I can not edit the classes `CA`, `CB` and `CC`. I also can not edit the classes/return types of `x()` and `y()`. All those types come from an external library.

Comment: Hum... seams to be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... What do you want to achieve ? what is real problem you want to achieve with this design ? First idea that come to me is you try to reimplement `virtual` inheritance

Comment: You cannot. Determining which template to use at runtime will always induce that ugly switch at every use, and you cannot factor it out into a function either. The next best thing is polymorphism with a function that returns a `unique_ptr<base_class>` that actually points to the correct class (factory pattern).

Comment: @nwp One can write a compiler generated jump table in some cases to replace the switch.  Or chain ifs.  Or ...  It is only sometimes an improvement, but your use of "always" is simply wrong.

Comment: @Yakk You are right, you *can* implement the switch using if-chains or goto and say you didn't use switch. While technically correct it is wrong in the spirit of the question. The goal is to avoid having to write the mapping code each use, not to avoid the switch keyword.

Comment: @nwp or I could generate the mappimg from two parallel lists with nothing but the index associating them.  If I have control over the enum, the values of the enum are a sufficient list.  My point is you made an over strong claim, and we do not *know* what criteria would make a solution "better" than the OP's switch statement.  Plus the OP is asking how to make two independant switch statements work, which is also quite viable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use continuation passing style.

```
template <class F> void applyFunc(WhichFunc w, T t, F f)
{
  switch(w)
  {
    case X: f(t.x());
    case Y: f(t.y());
  }
}

template<class F>
void getBase(Base b, Foo foo, F f)
{
  switch(b)
  {
    case A: f(foo.a);
    case B: f(foo.b);
    case C: f(foo.c);
  }
}
```

Where instead of returning, you pass the next step as a parameter to the previous.

```
Func f;
Base b;
Foo foo;

getBase(b, [&](auto&&b){ applyFunc( f, b, [&](auto&& r){ use(r); } ); } );
```

or somesuch (there may be typos).

`std::variant` (or boost) can be used to move the continuation until after the return value.

```
auto b = getBase(b);
auto r = visit( b, [&](auto&& b){ return applyFunc( f, b ); } );
visit( r, [](auto&& r){ use(r); } );
```

where instead of taking a continuation, each of the above returns a `variant<possible_return_types_go_here>`.

Answer (score 1):

In short: you can not. The return type of a function must to be well-known a *compile time*. Indeed, trying to return different types within a function with `auto` return type, it will give you a compiler error, even if you use template.

Probably your solution consists into the usage of *polymorfism*.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is using traits:

```
struct Foo { class CA {}; class CB {}; class CC {}; CA a; CB b; CC c; };
enum Base { A, B, C, };
enum Func { X, Y, }; 

template<Base> struct GetBaseTraits;
template<> struct GetBaseTraits<Base::A> { using type = Foo::CA; };
template<> struct GetBaseTraits<Base::B> { using type = Foo::CB; };
template<> struct GetBaseTraits<Base::C> { using type = Foo::CC; };

template<Base b>
typename GetBaseTraits<b>::type getBase(Foo f);

template<> typename GetBaseTraits<A>::type getBase<A>(Foo f) { return f.a; }
template<> typename GetBaseTraits<B>::type getBase<B>(Foo f) { return f.b; }
template<> typename GetBaseTraits<C>::type getBase<C>(Foo f) { return f.c; }

int main() {
    Foo f{};
    Foo::CA ca = getBase<A>(f);
    Foo::CB cb = getBase<B>(f);
    Foo::CC cc = getBase<C>(f);
}
```

Comment: But this does not work when the template parameter for `getBase` is a runtime variable, right?

Comment: @Uroc327 Right. I didn't understand it was a requirement. If it's so, I'm deleting the answer in a while.

Answer (score 0):

A function should always return values with the same data type, determined at compile time. What you can do is use some form of variant, for example [boost::variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/variant.html), or create your own variant type:

```
enum ReturnType {
  RET_STR, RET_INT, RET_DBL
};

struct variant {
  ReturnType valtype;
  string str;
  int i;
  double d;
};

string f1() { ... }
int f2() { ... }
double f3() { ... }

variant f(int x) {
  variant v;
  switch (x) {
   case 0:
    v.valtype = RET_STR;
    v.str = f1();
    break;
   case 1:
    v.valtype = RET_INT;
    v.str = f2();
    break;
   case 2:
    v.valtype = RET_DBL;
    v.str = f3();
    break;
  }
  return v;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use some form of polymorphism:

```
class result_handler {
public:
  virtual ~result_handler(){}
  virtual void handle_string(string s) = 0;
  virtual void handle_int(int i) = 0;
  virtual void handle_double(double d) = 0;
};

void f(int x, result_handler* h) {
  switch (x) {
    case 0:
      h->handle_string(f1());
      break;
    case 1:
      h->handle_int(f2());
      break;
    case 2:
      h->handle_double(f3());
      break;
  }
}

class my_result_handler : public result_handler {
public:
  virtual void handle_string(string s) { cout << "string " << s << endl; }
  virtual void handle_int(int i) { cout << "int " << i << endl; }
  virtual void handle_double(double d) { cout << "double " << d << endl; }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use tag dispatching if arguments are known at compile time:

```
template <Base> BaseTag{};

decltype(auto) getBaseImpl(Foo& foo, BaseTag<Base::A>) { return foo.a; }
decltype(auto) getBaseImpl(Foo& foo, BaseTag<Base::B>) { return foo.b; }
decltype(auto) getBaseImpl(Foo& foo, BaseTag<Base::C>) { return foo.c; }

template <Base base>
decltype(auto) getBase(Foo& foo) { return getBaseImpl(foo, BaseTag<base>{}); }

template <Func> FuncTag{};

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) getFuncImpl(T& t, FuncTag<Func::X>) { return t.x(); }
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) getFuncImpl(T& t, FuncTag<Func::Y>) { return t.y(); }

template <typename T, Func func>
decltype(auto) getFunc(T& t) { return getFuncImpl(f, FuncTag<func>{}); }
```

And finally:

```
template <Base base, Func func>
decltype(auto) getElem(Foo& foo) { return getFunc<func>(getBase<base>(foo)); }
```